# OAuth consent screen...Application Name

Tags: google-drive-api

in OAuth consent screen...Application Name

in am inputting following value

https://vps54475.inmotionhosting.com:2087/googledriveauth/callback

and getting below error

Application name must be less than 64 characters.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to specify callback in the wrong field.

Comment: The link you posted doesn't work. What is the value you are trying to put?